# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wraps'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get Django running on a shared hosting account for which I have ssh access, but I have been having issues getting it working.  When I first tried running django-admin.py, I received an error about the module 'functools' being missing.  I had the hosting company install the functools package, but now I get the following traceback when I try to run django-admin.py.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_manager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from optparse import OptionParser, NO_DEFAULT
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/optparse.py", line 90, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/gettext.py", line 49, in <module>
    import locale, copy, os, re, struct, sys
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/locale.py", line 98, in <module>
    @functools.wraps(_localeconv)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wraps'
```

I opened a support ticket and was told by the company that they reinstalled Python 2.6, but that didn't change anything.  I also tried with 2.4, which is also installed on the machine, but that resulted in the earlier `ImportError: No module named functools` error.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

A likely cause is something shadowing the stdlib `functools` module. Do you have a `functools.py` alongside the main script (`manage.py`)? See what `import functools; print functools.__file__` prints, inside `manage.py` (*before* any of the other imports.) If it doesn't print `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/functools.py`, there's probably a file shadowing the standard library module. If it *does* print that, something is wrong with that file, reinstalls notwithstanding.

Comment: It prints `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/functools-0.5-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/functools.pyc`.  Functools.py does exist at the path you mentioned as well.

Is there a way I can force python to import from `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/functools.py` and see if that fixes things?

Comment: I would open a support ticket with your host and ask them to remove the functools package from site-packages.

Answer (score 0):

this solution worked for me .

```
mv /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip* ./
yum reinstall python-pip
sudo pip install django
```

**or** try an another solution .

its too risky and this might not be a safest solution.but it worked fine for me .

1. uninstall pip.

   ```
   pip uninstall pip
   ```

   if you installed by **get-pip.py** .

   ```
    python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
   ```
2. navigate to the path.

   ```
     /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
   ```

   and find out two pip directories **pip** and **pip-6.0.8.dist-info**.
3. remove both **pip** and **pip-6.0.8.dist-info**.
4. then try again.

   ```
    yum install python-pip
   ```

   or

   ```
   python get-pip.py
   ```